# got an AttributeError: object has no attribute "name" but that's a class, not an attribute

Tags: python, flask

So i'm stuck at this flask application, i'm not still used very well to Python so i guess it will be a pretty simple error

```
    @app.route('/add-item/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @login_required
    def add_item():
        form = AddItemForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            name = form.item_name.data
            category_name = form.category_name.data
            print category_name
            kind = form.feedback.data
            text = form.review.data
            image_name = secure_filename(form.image.data.filename)
            print(image_name)
            image_data = form.image.data
            filepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], image_name)
            image_data.save(filepath.encode('utf-8'))
            itm = item.Item(name, g.user, category_name)
            rev = review.Review(text, g.user, kind)
            vow = vote.Vote(itm.id, g.user.id, VOTE_UP) #THIS LINE SEEMS TO TRIGGER THE ERROR
            pht = photo.Photo(filepath, g.user, itm.id)
            db.insert_review(rev)
            db.insert_vote(vow)
            db.insert_photo(pht)
            itm.reviews.append(rev)
            itm.votes.append(vow)
            itm.photos.append(pht)
            db.insert_item(itm)
            return render_template('item-added.html', title="item added successfully")
        else:
            return render_template('add-item.html', title="new item", form=form)
```

I get this error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2013 13:11:17] "POST /add-item/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_login.py", line 658, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\PycharmProjects\byb\byb.py", line 92, in add_item
    vow = vote.Vote(itm.id, g.user.id, VOTE_UP)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Vote'
```

My problem is i can't really understand why i get such an error: vote is a file (vote.py) and Vote is a class, i'm quite confused, any hints (also i'm not sure if i formatted correctly and if the title makes sense)

Comment: You might have defined a function with the same name.

Comment: Where do you declare `vote`? Can you show where the class is declared?

Comment: You have a *function* named `vote` in your module. Double-check that you didn't create `def vote()` somewhere, or imported `vote` from another module.

Comment: Yeah it works now, i edited a function name to "vote" and totally didn't think of it, thanks

Comment: Well if you make a separate comment with your answer I can select it as accepted answer :)